# Google Analytics API fails to login with bad request and invalidKey

Tags: authentication, google-analytics, google-oauth

I´m trying to get some data from analytics, but can´t get authorized. It returns the following error:

I renewed my credentials at google console several times.

The code I´m using:

```
var clientId = '*****************0m1fnmuae00abaaq.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = '********fB9eVMVfQ0oR6';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';


function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
}


function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}


function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult) {
    gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3', handleAuthorized);
  } else {
    handleUnauthorized();
  }
}


function handleAuthorized() {
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  var runDemoButton = document.getElementById('run-demo-button');

  authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  runDemoButton.style.visibility = '';
  runDemoButton.onclick = makeApiCall;
  outputToPage('Click the Run Demo button to begin.');
}


function handleUnauthorized() {
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  var runDemoButton = document.getElementById('run-demo-button');

  runDemoButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
  authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
  outputToPage('Please authorize this script to access Google Analytics.');
}


function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
  return false;
}
```

When I run the code, it returns the following error:

```
error: {errors:[{domain:usageLimits, reason:keyInvalid, message:Bad Request}], code:400, message:Bad Request}
code: 400
errors: [{domain:usageLimits, reason:keyInvalid, message:Bad Request}]
0: {domain:usageLimits, reason:keyInvalid, message:Bad Request}
domain: "usageLimits"
message: "Bad Request"
reason: "keyInvalid"
message: "Bad Request"
```

Someone can help with this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Find the error.

In Google Console, you have to create  the OAuth ID and the Public API Access ID.

Take the cliendId from the first and the APIKey from the second.

I think it´s very confuse, and it could be more explicit in documentation.